# segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Could anyone tell me why am i getting error when I try to push

```
   #include <stdio.h>


typedef struct Element
{
  struct Element *next;
  void *data;
}Element;

bool createStack(Element **stack)
{
  *stack = NULL;
  return true;
}

bool push (Element **stack, void *data)
{
  Element *new_element = new Element;

  if(!new_element)
  {
    printf("Memory allocation error in push");

    return false;
  }

  new_element->data = data;
  new_element->next = *stack;
  *stack            = new_element;
  return true;

}

bool pop (Element **stack, void *popped_data)
{
  if(!*stack)
  {
    printf("Stack empty");

    return false;
  }


  Element *new_head = new Element;

  popped_data   = (*stack)->data;
  new_head      = (*stack)->next;
  delete *stack;
  return true;

}

bool emptyStack(Element **stack)
{
  if(!*stack)
  {
    printf("Stack empty");

    return false;
  }

  Element *delete_ele;

  while(*stack)
  {
    delete_ele=*stack;
    *stack = delete_ele->next;
    delete delete_ele;
  }

  return true;

}

int main()
{

  int i,*j;
  Element *stacka = new Element;

  while(i!=5)
  {
    printf("Enter ur choice \n");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    if(i==1)
    {
      if(createStack(&stacka))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

    if(i==2)
    {
      *j=2;
      if(push(&stacka,j))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

    if(i==3)
    {
      if(pop(&stacka,j))
      {

        printf("yes %d",*j);


      }
    }

    if(i==4)
    {
      if(emptyStack(&stacka))
      {
        printf("yes");

      }
    }

  }
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help running it on ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried running under valgrind?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++`? Apart from the `new` keyword, this is C code. You need to either get a *good* book on C++, or accept that you're learning C instead.

Comment: Compiling with `g++ -Wall` prints `warning: ‘j’ may be used uninitialized in this function`, and would have saved you the trouble of posting here.

Comment: I understand there are pros and I am not and i accept it

Comment: I dunno how to use it !! sorry !! jus starting programming

Comment: @koool: Make that your next priority: learn how to use a debugger! It's an indispensable tool for a programmer. Do as Keith says to compile with warnings enabled and don't ignore them! And find a [good introductory C++ book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks), that will be of great help!

Comment: @unkulunkulu: -1 yourself (if I could). Being a beginner is not a crime. Don't downvote people for not yet having learned everything you know. Don't be a jerk.

Comment: @jalf, "a jerk" doesn't mean what you implied here.

Comment: yes it does. And I didn't "imply" anything. I don't think "imply" means what you think it means. Calling someone a jerk when they behave like a jerk isn't an implication.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes thanks ... I just learned the gdb and how to single step and add break points is there anything else I should look into.... I mean besides gdb ......

Comment: @koool: If you can handle gdb that should be fine for now. Single stepping, using breakpoints and watching the values of variables should be enough to figure out a lot of problems. When that fails, you can always come and ask here :) Oh, and in the future, try to reduce your code to as short as possible a piece that still reproduces your problem. Often you can figure out the problem yourself just by doing that. There's a lot more to learn in the road ahead. Have fun!

Comment: @R. Martinho fernandes Thanks!! for ur valuable guidance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in this line

```
*j = 2;
```

`j` is uninitialized at that point.

You should either push `&k` where `k` is an `int`, or initialize `j = new int`. Memory leak avoidance is up to you in the latter case.

Comment: Also `pop` isn't updating `stack`.

Comment: @unkulunkulu - exactly, so once you've popped an element, you cant access any of the ones after it, nor can you use the variable passed to `pop` safely.

Comment: Nice !! @Node yup jus noticed that corrected ... thanks for pointing out

Comment: @koool: pop is also leaking an element at `new_head = new Element`. Think about it: if you're taking things from the stack, why do you need to create something?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `int i,*j;`, `j` is just an uninitialized pointer that doesn't point to a valid memory location. Later, when you say `*j=2;`, you dereference that pointer, which results in undefined behaviour.

You have to assign a meaningful location to `j`, like so:

```
int j_content;
int *j = &j_content;
```